# Going from multiple dummy variables to a single variable

Tags: r, variables, dataframe

How can I take `n` dummy variables that are mutually exclusive in a data frame and concatenate them into a single variable? In the following example

```
k <- data.frame(H=sample(c(T, F), 100, T))
ifelse(k$H==T, F, sample(c(T, F))) -> k$k
k$u <- ifelse(k$H==T | k$k==T, F, T)
```

is there an easy method of converting these into one variable `i` with levels `H`, `k` or `u`?

I guess you could do it with `ifelse` etc., in this example, but in my data file I have several hundred dummies and I´m too lazy to do this manually.

Comment: Why does the `->` operator exist anyway? It's awful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
k$i <- names(k)[apply(k, 1, which)]
```

will convert bool into one dummy variable.

Comment: Sweet:-)... And if they are coded as H/non-H,k/non-k and u/non-u or Na instead of non- How would you go about doing that?

Comment: Sorry I cannot get what you mean. More info please.